# Replacing text with another one

Tags: macros, letters

I need a command to replace the text from left to right given below. for example the command should change `Ã¼` into `\"{u}`.
I found some command about this but i could't apply.

```
{Ã¼}{\"{u}}
{ÄŸ}{\u{g}}
{Ä±}{\i}
{ÅŸ}{\c{s}}
{Ã§}{\c{c}}
{Ã}{\"{o}}
{Ãœ}{\"{U}}
{Ä}{\u{G}}
{Ä°}{\.{I}}
{Å}{\c{S}}
{Ã‡}{\c{C}}
{Ã--}{\"{O}}
```

Comment: It seems that you can use a proper editor to change and replace strings; not that it should be done via TeX.

Comment: can "sed" command make this?

Comment: Is this just some utf8 file being read in an 8 bit encoding? (that is the usual cause of accented A appearing in strange places)? If so you should be able just declare the correct encoding rather than edit the file.

Comment: Try putting `\usepackage{selinput} \SelectInputMappings{ udieresis={ü},odieresis={ö}}` in your document instead of loading package `inputenc`.

Comment: Voted unclear; no response to the latest salient comments.